# Show html data in jquery data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using following code to display a button on the last column of the jquery data table. But it is displaying the raw html code. Is there is a way to display the button instead of the html code? greatly appreciate your help

```
        $(document).ready(function() {  

             $('#test').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );

            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "data": results,

                "columnDefs": [
                    { "type": "html", 
                      "targets": -1                          
                    } 
                ],
                "columns": [
                    { "title": "A", "data" : "id" },
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    { "title": "B" , "data" : "buttonUrl" },

                ]
            } );                
       } );
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
{ "title": "B" , "data" : "buttoUrl" },
```

should probably be something like this

```
{ "title": "B" , "data" : "<a href='buttoUrl'>My button</a>" },
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Here i need to pass data from a JSON array and the button url is dynamic